# MathKernel Very Slow

Tags: performance-tuning

I developed a Mathematica package using Mathematica 12.1 and I am calling this package from my java code: I generate a system of equations (where I call the package) from the java code, then send this system to the Mathematica Kernel to solve it, but it takes at least 2 or 3 minutes to return a result (and sometimes keeps running). When I run Mathematica front end to solve the same system, it takes few microseconds. Can anyone tell me why is Mathematica Kernel is extremely slow?

thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Tell us more about your Java setup and how you are invoking the kernel. Have you followed an(y) example from a tutorial that worked better etc. Thanks.

Comment: I am working with Intellij Idea and use jlink, this is the java code where I create a connection with Mathematica then call Mathematica Kernel :  
KernelLink ml;                                                                                                                                      String s = "-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\12.1\\MathKernel.exe'";    ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(s);
 ml.connect();  ml.discardAnswer(); 
String res = ml.evaluateToInputForm(exp,0);       //exp=<<MyPackage;UsingFrontEnd[MyPackageFunc[]]

Comment: No I am not following any tutorial. thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share some examples of the code in the package?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, I could finally solve the problem by simply sending two seperate commands to Mathematica kernel from my java code: in the first command I evaluate the call to my package, and in the second command, I evaluate the system of equations (that uses my package). So instead of send one command of the form:

```
ml.evaluateToOutputForm(<<Mypackage`;systemOfEquationsToSolve)
```

I send the following two commands:

```
ml.evaluateToOutputForm("<<MyPackage`");
ml.discardAnswer();
ml.evaluateToOutputForm(systemOfEquationsToSolve);
```

Comment: If the function `f` is define in `SomePackage`, then a combined ``(Get["SomePackage`"]; f[])`` is not equivalent to evaluating these two commands separately. The package must be loaded _before_ `f[]` is parsed (note: parsed, not merely evaluated). Otherwise `f` will be interpreted in the `Global` context, not in your package's context.